# Port Forwarding to another machine Rust gameserver

Tags: networking, server, steam, iptables, firewall

I need to forward UDP port 28015 of my local machine to another machine with port UDP 28021. Rust Game Server. (Redirect incoming traffic on a specific port to a different IP address with altern port)

Tried: sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 28015 -j DNAT --to-destination another_server:28021 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

the traffic is redirected, but when you enter the server itself, the "Steam Auth Failed" error pops up.

The problem is not in the server, because when trying to redirect not to mine, but to any other server, the same error pops up.

Comment: Look up rathole on GitHub. Not totally sure, but that might do what you’re looking for

Comment: No, I need to do a redirect without access to the final server.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using `socat`, no need to NAT in this case

```
$ socat udp-listen:28015,reuseaddr,fork udp:another_server:28021
```

If you do want to use iptables you can use the following

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type LOCAL -p udp --dport 28015 -j DNAT --to-destination another_server:28021
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type UNICAST -j MASQUERADE
$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

Comment: Or using the program `udppm` from a great package 3proxy (https://3proxy.ru/): `udppm -d 28015 another_server 28021`